# How to access files on a networked smb server with Python on macOS

Tags: macos, network, python, smb, file-sharing

I have a bunch of files that sit on a networked drive to which I can connect by using Finder > Go > Connect to Server and entering the address `smb://smb-name.institute.name.org/DRIVENAME` and then entering my credentials. [image: How I connect to the shared folders/files]

But I need to connect to this from Python so I can run Python code that analyzes those files. How can I do so?

So far I tried the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120083/mount-windows-smb-shares-on-a-mac-using-python/306736) but nothing seems to happen when I do this. (I do not need to copy or clone the files over to my computer, I just need to access them from Python so perhaps this is not the right thing to do anyway.)

I also found [this](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html) by Googling but am getting a ConnectionRefused error when I execute the line `assert conn.connect(server_ip, 139)` where I set `server_ip` to be the URL I used to connect my Mac or a "gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known" depending on if I enter just the beginning part or the whole URL.

I would appreciate any help as I am new to smb, networking and all of this and connecting to a networked drive with Python on a Mac.

Comment: Can you respond to this? Specially, running from terminal? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120086/263848

Comment: Did that command work?

Comment: Do /Labname in terminal

Comment: you mean just `/Labname` ? I get : No such file or directory.

Comment: "except that I use Labname as Volumename" dont

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83638/discussion-between-semihcan-doken-and-jbis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing in chat the OP was able to solve the issue by creating a mount point.

1. `sudo mkdir /Volumes/test`
2. `sudo mount_smbfs //user:pass@url.com/folder /Volumes/Test`

This can be done with python by eliminating the `sudo` but running the script/application as admin.

Comment: Thanks @JBis. This worked. But I guess something else needs to be done to continue to access the files after the computer has been restarted? Currently, I am not able to access it anymore, the Volume is no longer visible.