# Accessing a NAS device from Python code on Mac-OS

Tags: macos, python, nas

I have a NAS device that appears in Finder under the Shared devices so I can read and write to it just like any folder on my OSX drive with no need to provide authentication.  How can I read and write to it from Python code?  I have tried manually accessing required folders on the drive so that they then appear in Volumes, but I still can't get at them.

Comment: Can you clarify this slightly? Are you trying to mount the network shares via python, or are you just trying to read/write to already mounted shares? What happens when you use os.chdir() to select a filepath on the shares as the current working dir?

Comment: I think what I am missing is what is the filepath to use for the NAS box that is already being shared with OSX

Comment: How did you manually access them?

Comment: I just click on them in Finder (under Shared - not Devices)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mount the network volume (or make sure that it is mounted) from the python code, then you could use the shell command `mount`, from inside an `os.system()` call. [See this answer.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120083/mount-windows-smb-shares-on-a-mac-using-python)

Once mounted, you can access the contents of the drive like any other connected drive with a filepath under /Volumes.
It is likely to be something like:
`/Volumes/My\ NAS/path/to/file` (where "My NAS" is the name of your share.)

Note that whether the Finder shows the drive under "Devices" or "Shared" is irrelevant.

If you need to find the filepath for a given item on the NAS, use Command Alt C in the Finder to copy the filepath to the clipboard as text.

If the correct path still isn't working in your python, then we need to see your python code.

Comment: Command Alt C works fine for items listed under Devices in Finder (thanks I didn't know that) but doesn't seem to do anything for devices listed under Shared, which is where my NAS box is.

Comment: Have you tried an actual path to a file or folder on the device, rather than the device itself?

Comment: The problem is I don't know the path to the device.  Do I need to use its IP address?  Finder doesn't seem to need it.

Comment: Can you browse files on the device in the Finder?

Comment: Yes no problem in Finder

Comment: So when you select a file on the device in the Finder, and press Command Alt C, what filepath do you get?

Comment: I get the path of the Device eg: /Volumes/LaCie 4Tbt.  But as my NAS box is on the network and not connected directly to my computer it does not show up in Devices, it shows up in Shared.

Comment: That doesn't matter. If the device is mounted, then
"`/Volumes/LaCie 4Tbt/folder/folder/myfile.ext`" is a valid filepath that should work in python. You should also be able to navigate and work with files on this path in the Terminal.

Comment: I am sorry I am obviously not being clear.  The Lacie drive is attached to my computer and so appears in Devices.  My NAS box is on my network and so does not appear under Devices.  It appears under Shared and Command Alt C does nothing to the clipboard when I select it.  I have found that if I select a folder within my NAS box then it mounts that folder and it does become accessible via '/Volumes/' so it looks like what I need is a way of mounting the folders on a network drive from within Python rather then by selecting them manually in Finder.

Comment: See my edit to my original answer.

Comment: @THobson Have you got the path of a **file** on the NAS not a directory?